# Show table rows dynamically using button HTML + PHP + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table that consist of 40 rows.
I need to fix my code so that initially one row should appear, and at the end of row i need a button to **show** the next row and so on.

Kind of the below screenshot [image]

Currently my code looks like this:

```
<table align="center" id="dataTable" border=1>
<tr class="header">
<th class='text ce6'><Strong>Product Code</Strong></th>
<th class='text ce6'><Strong>Desc</Strong></th>
<th class='text ce6'><Strong>Qty</Strong></th>
<th class='text ce6'><Strong>Unit</Strong></th>
<?php
for ($i = 1 ; $i < 40 ; $i++)
    {  //Loop the table 
    echo "<select type='select' name='ProductCode";
    echo $i;
    echo "' id ='ProductCodee'  size='1' onchange='GetDesc(this)'> ";
    echo "<option value=''>-Select Type-</option>";
    for($x = 0; $x<=40; $x++)
       {
        echo "<option value='";
        echo $arrProducts[$x+1];    
        echo "'>";
        echo $arrProducts[$x];
        echo "</option>";
        $x = $x + 2;
        }
    echo"</select>";
?>
<td><input size=25 type="text" id="desc" readonly=true/></td>
<td><input size=5 type="number" id="qty" /></td>
<td><input size=5 type="text" id="unit" readonly=true/></td>
<td><INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" /</td>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: do you really want to force th user to click 40 times?

Comment: No @e4c5 it's optional, whatever he selects, that will be the posted rows.

Comment: @AhmedAli So the idea is to add only a single row as the user clicks but the maximum should be 40?

Comment: Exactly,40 is the maximum and user can add any more rows he want.

Comment: I can't really see where the problem/error is? Or do you think we are here to code it for you?

Comment: well @WaKai thanks for your useful support, ask me what you don't understand and i will explain it to you, if i want someone to code it for me, i would've hire someone to do my job.

Comment: @AhmedAli You are welcome, no need to thank me. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask this could be useful for you. It is still unclear which problems occured while you tried to resolve your problem. Have you tried?

Comment: @WaKai as i can see from your profile, you don't have even enough experience to judge the way i asked my question. you better try to edit the question or correct it,rather than what you did.

Comment: @AhmedAli Oh I didn't knew, that someone with less score than you isn't allowed to ask where the exact problem is. I would gladly edit or correct the question if there would be any sign of a problem you encountered during solving it, like I already asked by my first comment. As long as you can't name the problem or the error, it looks like you haven't even tried it. If this is not true, then please tell us your problem with this and we try to help you. That's how SO works, someone with your score should know that...

Comment: @WaKai if you don't see any problem here, why other are already trying to answer this queston?? let's be honest this was not a proper way to ask for clarification.

Comment: This question shows how people are willing to code for someone else in exchange of some reputation, despite the question quality. **-5** means something, after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start with, issue all rows but the first one with a class hidden...

```
for ($i = 1 ; $i < 40 ; $i++)
    {  //Loop the table 
    if ( $i=1 )
        echo "<tr><td>";  // <= new
    else
        echo "<tr><td class='hidden'>";  // <= new
    // going on as before:
    echo "<select type='select' name='ProductCode";
```

...of course close that `</tr>` at the end of your loop. The CSS is simple:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

The javascript for your show-button would be quite simple. Unhide the first hidden row. For simplicity, I am using jQuery, but plain vanilla javascript would be very close:

```
function addRow() {
    // find the table in which your button just got clicked:
    var $table = $(this).parents('table');
    // find the first hidden row and unhide (show) it:
    $table.find('tr.hidden:first').removeClass('hidden');

    ... other stuff you intend to do as part of addRow()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple and easy you can edit it easily as you want.

Javascript Code

```
<script>
  function addRow()
  {

    var html = '';
    html += '<tr>';
    html +='<td><select><option> Select Bundle</option>';

    for(var i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        html += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
    }

    html +='</select>';
    html +='</td>';
    html += '<td>Desc...</td>';
    html +='<td>2</td>';
    html +='<td>52</td>';
    html +='<td><button onclick="addRow();">Add</button></td>';
    html +='</tr>';
    $('tbody').append(html);

  }
</script>
```

HTML + PHP

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Project Code</th>
                <th>Desc</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                            <option> Select Bundle</option>
                    <?php
                        for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++)
                        {
                            echo '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
                        }
                    ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>Desc...</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>52</td>
                    <td><button onclick="addRow();">Add</button></td>
                </tr>    
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

In select tag you can manage function of javascript as per your requirement.

Remember I used jQuery to add new row ion table please use any jQuery version.

Good Luck.. ['}

Comment: if you satisfied just mark as correct and accept it so other can get easily the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

it is in codeigniter frame work 
update view part is

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap-fileinput.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-fileinput/bootstrap-fileinput.js"></script>
<div class="page-container">
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE HEAD -->
    <div class="page-head">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE -->
            <div class="page-title">
                <h1><?php echo $title_text; ?> Management</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE TITLE -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE HEAD -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT -->
    <div class="page-content">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE BREADCRUMB -->
            <ul class="page-breadcrumb breadcrumb">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Home</a>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('administration/options'); ?>"><?php echo $title_text; ?></a>
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('administration/options/update/' . $details->option_id . '/' . $page); ?>">Update <?php echo $title_text; ?></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <!-- END PAGE BREADCRUMB -->
            <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTENT INNER -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="tabbable tabbable-custom tabbable-noborder tabbable-reversed">
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="tab_0" class="tab-pane active">
                                <div class="portlet box blue">
                                    <div class="portlet-title">
                                        <div class="caption">
                                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                            Update <?php echo $title_text; ?>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) { ?>
                                        <div class="Metronic-alerts alert alert-danger fade in">
                                            <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" type="button"></button>
                                            <i class="fa-lg fa fa-warning"></i>
                                            <?php
                                            echo $_SESSION['error'];
                                            unset($_SESSION['error']);
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="portlet-body form">
                                    <!-- BEGIN FORM-->
                                    <?php echo form_open_multipart('administration/options/update/' . $details->option_id . '/' . $page); ?>
                                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                                        <div class="form-body">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="counter" id="counter" value="<?php echo $counter ?>">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Option Name:<span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Option Type" value = "<?php
                                                    if (validation_errors() == '')
                                                        echo $details->name;
                                                    else
                                                        echo set_value('name');
                                                    ?>" class="form-control">
                                                    <span class="custom-error help-block help-block-error"><?php echo form_error('name') ?></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Select Option Type<span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></label>
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <select class="form-control" name="type" autocomplete="off">
                                                        <optgroup label="Choose">
                                                            <option <?php
                                                            if (!empty(validation_errors()))
                                                                echo set_select('type', 'select');
                                                            elseif ($details->type == 'select')
                                                                echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                            ?> value="select">Select</option>
                                                            <option <?php
                                                            if (!empty(validation_errors()))
                                                                echo set_select('type', 'radio');
                                                            elseif ($details->type == 'radio')
                                                                echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                            ?> value="radio">Radio</option>
                                                            <option <?php
                                                            if (!empty(validation_errors()))
                                                                echo set_select('type', 'checkbox');
                                                            elseif ($details->type == 'checkbox')
                                                                echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                            ?> value="checkbox">Checkbox</option>
                                                            <option <?php
                                                            if (!empty(validation_errors()))
                                                                echo set_select('type', 'image');
                                                            elseif ($details->type == 'image')
                                                                echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                            ?> value="image">Image</option>
                                                        </optgroup>
                                                        <optgroup label="Input">
                                                            <option <?php
                                                            if (!empty(validation_errors()))
                                                                echo set_select('type', 'text');
                                                            elseif ($details->type == 'text')
                                                                echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                            ?> value="text">Text</option>
                                                            <option <?php
                                                            if (!empty(validation_errors()))
                                                                echo set_select('type', 'textarea');
                                                            elseif ($details->type == 'textarea')
                                                                echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                            ?> value="textarea">Textarea</option>
                                                        </optgroup>
                                                        <optgroup label="File">
                                                            <option <?php
                                                            if (!empty(validation_errors()))
                                                                echo set_select('type', 'file');
                                                            elseif ($details->type == 'file')
                                                                echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                            ?> value="file">File</option>
                                                        </optgroup>
                                                        <optgroup label="Date">
                                                            <option <?php
                                                            if (!empty(validation_errors()))
                                                                echo set_select('type', 'date');
                                                            elseif ($details->type == 'date')
                                                                echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                            ?> value="date">Date</option>
                                                            <option <?php
                                                            if (!empty(validation_errors()))
                                                                echo set_select('type', 'time');
                                                            elseif ($details->type == 'time')
                                                                echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                            ?> value="time">Time</option>
                                                            <option <?php
                                                            if (!empty(validation_errors()))
                                                                echo set_select('type', 'datetime');
                                                            elseif ($details->type == 'datetime')
                                                                echo 'selected="selected"';
                                                            ?> value="datetime">Date &amp; Time</option>
                                                        </optgroup>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <span class = "custom-error help-block help-block-error"><?php echo form_error('type'); ?></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group last">
                                                <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Sort Order:</label>
                                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                                    <input type="text" name="sort_order" placeholder="1" value = "<?php
                                                    if (validation_errors() == '')
                                                        echo $details->sort_order;
                                                    else
                                                        echo set_value('sort_order');
                                                    ?>" class="form-control">
                                                    <span class="custom-error help-block help-block-error"><?php echo form_error('sort_order') ?></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="portlet-body flip-scroll">
                                                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content" id="options">
                                                    <thead class="flip-content">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th>
                                                                <span class="control-label">Option Value Name<span class="required" aria-required="true"> * </span></span>
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th> Image
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                                Sort Order
                                                            </th>
                                                            <th>
                                                            </th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <?php
                                                        if ($counter) {
                                                            for ($count = 0; $count < $counter; $count++):
                                                                ?>
                                                                <tr id="<?php echo 'rowno_' . $count; ?>">
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <input type="hidden" name="option_value[pimage][]" value = "<?php
                                                                        if (validation_errors() == '')
                                                                            echo $choices[$count]->image;
                                                                        else
                                                                            echo set_value("option_value[pimage][$count]");
                                                                        ?>">
                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                                <input type="text" name="option_value[name][]" placeholder="Option Name" value = "<?php
                                                                                if (validation_errors() == '')
                                                                                    echo $choices[$count]->name;
                                                                                else
                                                                                    echo set_value("option_value[name][$count]");
                                                                                ?>" class="form-control">
                                                                                <span class="custom-error help-block help-block-error"><?php echo form_error("option_value[name][$count]"); ?></span>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                                <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                                                                                    <div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
                                                                                        <?php if (isset($choices[$count])) {
                                                                                            ?>
                                                                                            <img src="<?php echo base_url() . 'uploads/options/' . $choices[$count]->image ?>" alt="<?php echo $choices[$count]->image; ?>"/>
                                                                                        <?php }
                                                                                        ?>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                    <div class = "fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style = "max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px;"></div>
                                                                                    <div>
                                                                                        <span class = "btn default btn-file">
                                                                                            <span class = "fileinput-new">Select image </span>
                                                                                            <span class = "fileinput-exists">Change </span>
                                                                                            <input type = "file" name = "option_value[image][]">
                                                                                        </span>
                                                                                        <a href = "javascript:;" class = "btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss = "fileinput">Remove </a>
                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <div class = "form-group">
                                                                            <div class = "col-md-12">
                                                                                <input type = "text" name = "option_value[sort_order][]" value = "<?php
                                                                                if (validation_errors() == '')
                                                                                    echo $choices[$count]->sort_order;
                                                                                else
                                                                                    echo set_value("option_value[sort_order][$count]");
                                                                                ?>" placeholder = "1" class = "form-control">
                                                                                <span class = "custom-error help-block help-block-error"><?php echo form_error("option_value[sort_order][$count]")
                                                                                ?></span>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                    <td>
                                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                                                                <a>
                                                                                    <button type="button"  onclick="removerow(<?php echo "rowno_$count"; ?>)" class="btn default btn-md red" id="sample_editable_1_new">
                                                                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>
                                                                                </a>
                                                                            </div>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <?php
                                                            endfor;
                                                        }
                                                        ?>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                    <tfoot>
                                                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="btn-group">
                                                            <a>
                                                                <button onclick="addnewrow()" type="button" class="btn blue" id="sample_editable_1_new">
                                                                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                                </button>
                                                            </a>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                    </tfoot>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-actions">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">
                                                    <button class="btn blue" type="submit">Update <?php echo $title_text; ?></button>
                                                    <button class="btn default" type="button" onclick="history.go(-1);">Cancel</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php form_close(); ?>
                                    <!-- END FORM-->
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- END PAGE CONTENT INNER -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END PAGE CONTENT -->
<script>
    $('document').ready(function () {
        var val = $('select[name=\'type\']').val();
        if (val == 'select' || val == 'radio' || val == 'checkbox' || val == 'image') {
            $('#options').show();
        } else {
            $('#options').hide();
        }
    });

    $('select[name=\'type\']').on('change', function () {
        if (this.value == 'select' || this.value == 'radio' || this.value == 'checkbox' || this.value == 'image') {
            $('#options').show();
        } else {
            $('#options').hide();
        }
    });

    function removerow(id) {
        $(id).remove();
    }

    function addnewrow() {
        var counter = $('#counter').val();
        var row = '<tr id="rowno_' + counter + '">';
        row = row + '<td><input type="hidden" name="option_value[pimage][]" value = "0"><div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-12">';
        row = row + '<input type="text" name="option_value[name][]" placeholder="Option Name" class="form-control">';
        row = row + '</div></div></td><td><div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-12"><div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">';
        row = row + '<div class="fileinput-new thumbnail" style="width:100px; height:100px;"></div>';
        row = row + '<div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 100px; max-height: 100px;"></div>';
        row = row + '<div><span class="btn default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image </span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change </span>';
        row = row + '<input type="file" name="option_value[image][]">';
        row = row + '</span><a href="javascript:;" class="btn red fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove </a></div></div></div></div></td><td>';
        row = row + '<div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-12">';
        row = row + '<input type="text" name="option_value[sort_order][]" placeholder="Sort Order" class="form-control">';
        row = row + '</div></div></td><td>';
        row = row + '<div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-12"><a><button type="button"  onclick="removerow(' + 'rowno_' + counter + ')" class="btn default btn-md red" id="sample_editable_1_new"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button></a></div></div>';
        row = row + '</tr>';
        $("#options > tbody").append(row);
        counter++;
        $('#counter').val(counter);
    }
</script>
```

**and controller part is:**

i can't upload due to limit 30,000 :)